# Select in Concat mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, date, datetime, string-concatenation

I'm trying to get a date value with:
- Current year
- Current month
- Day number from one select

the query

```
SELECT rat_data FROM rate_unita WHERE rateid = 1
```

as a result one INT value.

When I try to execute the following:

```
SELECT DATE(CONCAT(YEAR(NOW())),(MONTH(NOW())), (SELECT rat_data FROM rate_unita WHERE rateid = 1))
```

*Mysql mark my syntax as incorrect near ' ( MONTH( NOW( ) ) ) , ( SELECT rat_data FROM rate_unita WHERE r*

I think that there is something wrong with the way I'm calling the SELECT in the CONCAT, what is the correct query to reach my goal?

Thanks
L

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're closing the concat function too early.  Remove some extra parentheis

```
SELECT DATE(CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()),
  MONTH(NOW()),
  (SELECT rat_data FROM rate_unita WHERE rateid = 1)
))
```

But you need to add some hyphens to make it a true date value

```
SELECT DATE(
  CONCAT(
    YEAR(NOW()),
    '-',
    MONTH(NOW()),
    '-',
    (SELECT rat_data FROM rate_unita WHERE rateid = 1)
  )
)
```

This should result in a date of `YEAR-MONTH-rat_data`

Here's a working [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b0576/2)

Answer (score 0):

Use DATE_FORMAT function. Here are a few examples:
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp
http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-date_format/

Comment: In addition to linking to an external site, you should show how to do what he's trying to do. Link-only answers are frowned upon.